# difficulties to convert flex into css/bootstrap, need help, check the given images

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap.

this is the required design

[image: required design],
and this is the outcome of my effort can't do it any better i've come this far

[image: i've come this far]

Comment: please describe more and share your code

Comment: Can you create [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?